# Почему бот отправляет сообщение "подождите" и когда уже отправляет ответ, то сообщение изменяется и удаляется?

Tags: python, асинхронность, python-openai

У меня есть бот chatgpt в телеграмм и есть функция генерации ответа:

```py
async def ai(prompt):
    global state
    completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k",
        temperature = 0.8,
        presence_penalty = 0.6,
        frequency_penalty = 0.6,
        messages=[
            {"role": "user", "content": prompt}
        ]
    )
    state = False
    return completion.choices[0].message.content
```

Данная функция генерирует ответ на запрос пользователя, и я хочу сделать анимацию при ожидании ответа. То есть когда пользователь отправляет вопрос в чат-бот, отправляет сообщение "подождите" и каждые 0.5с бот должен изменять сообщение и добавлять по 1 точке до трёх:

```py
async def edit_message(message):
    loop_counter = 0
    while state:
        await message.edit_text(f"ㅤ\n ⌛️ Ожидание ответа{'.' * (loop_counter % 4)}\nㅤ")
        loop_counter += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    await message.delete()
```

Но это не работает, бот отправляет сообщение "подождите" и когда бот уже отправляет ответ, то сообщение изменяется и удаляется, но стоит мне функцию ai() заменить на эту:

```py
async def ai(prompt):
    global state
    count = 0
    for i in range(25):
        count += 1
        print(count)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    state=False
    return "Отлично!"
```

тогда всё работает, в консоль печатаются числа, бот изменяет сообщение затем удаляет его и отправляет ответ.

Вызов функций выглядит так:

```py
@dp.message_handler()
async def gpt_answer(message: types.Message):
    global state
    state = True
    editing_message = await message.answer("ㅤ\n ✅ Запрос отправлен!\nㅤ")
    task_edit_msg = asyncio.create_task(edit_message(editing_message))
    task_gpt = asyncio.create_task(ai(message.text))

    await asyncio.gather(task_edit_msg, task_gpt)
    result = await task_gpt
    await message.reply(result, parse_mode="Markdown")
```

Comment: await openai.Completion.acreate

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря комментарию Сергея я узнал о openai.Completion.acreate - что является асинхронной версии openai.Completion.create